# Problem with connection to MS SQL Server database using SSMS

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssms

I have a database on line with Godaddy (who uses SQL Server 2005). They provide basic management tools, but tell you that for more advanced tools you can connect directly using SSMS. I followed their instructions to ensure my online database will accept remote connections, and can apparently log in using SSMS with success (after giving my hostname and access data).

However: Now from in SSMS, when attempting to expand the "Databases" folder tree, I get the following error:

```
Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&   LinkId=20476
```

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

The server principal "cmitchell" is not able to access the database "3pointdb" under the current security context. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 916)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=09.00.4262&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=916&LinkId=20476

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I been having the same problem but finally fix the issue.

http://clayburt.com/2009/12/28/godaddy-windows-hosting-ms-sql-2005-database-with-sql-management-studio-ssms-2008/

Read the direction carefully

1. Open SSMS
2. Connect to the Database with Godaddy
3. Open "Object Explorer Details"
4. Click on Database
5. Right-Click on any column name heading
6. Un-check collation column

I do know why this happen but it happen to fix the problem for me.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to have permissions to view that database. I would suggest GODaddy tech support would be the place to resolve the issue.

Comment: 3pointdb isn't my database. It is just another in a long list of databases that show up when I access my Godaddy backend.

From SSMS, I selected the default database to be the name of my database, which it did locate on the list when I browsed.

Still same error message. It is trying to connect to a database that isn't mine!  :(

Godaddy support, after a bit of testing, said the problem isn't on their end. it's on mine.